# Updating a module's model in Odoo 10

Tags: python, ubuntu, module, odoo, odoo-10

I'm having a trouble updating a model in odoo

the tables of my module won't change when I make changes to the model, even when I restart the server, upgrade the module, delete the module and reinstall it

is there a way to make the database synchronized with my model?

Answer (score 0):

If you save changes to the module, restart the server, and upgrade the module - all changes should be applied.

Changes to tables (e.g. fields) should only require the module to be upgraded, not a server reboot.

Python changes (e.g. contents of a method) require a server restart, not a module upgrade.

If the changes are not occurring, then it is possible that you have a different problem. I would look at things like: are you looking at the correct database/tables, are you saving your changes, are the changes being made to the correct files/in the correct locations.

Comment: I've checked what you have suggested, still can't update the model, by the way changes in xml files apply to the module unlike python files

Comment: changes to running python code are applied when the server reboots because this triggers a compile on the code. if you change an existing method then after a reboot it will change. xml changes e.g. view changes, are applied to the database - but these changes only occur when you install or upgrade a module. The only other option i can think of is that you have an xml with noupdate=1.

Comment: I'm not using 'noupdate', I've noticed that I can launch the Odoo web interface without the need of Odoo-bin command !, so I've checked the services ; there's postgres service running but no Odoo service at all, weird!  ,how can I really restart the Odoo server??

Answer (score 0):

Please check that in addons path there is no any duplicate folder having same name. Sometimes if there is zip file with same name in addons path than it doesn't get affect of any updation.

Comment: no there isn't, by the way changes in xml files apply to the module unlike python files

Comment: If you have issue with only python file, be sure that you import that file in __init__.py